# Scheduled task with GMSA fails when running remote exe

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, fileserver, gmsa

I have a scheduled task running as a GMSA account with highest privileges.  The task kicks off a cmd file that in turn calls two exe's.  One exe is on the server with the scheduled task.  The other exe is on a remote network share. The GMSA has modify rights to the remote directory.

The first exe runs fine.  The second exe immediately shows as suspended in task manager and dies.  The cmd file returns Error Level -532462766.  However, I cannot find info on this error code.

The scheduled task runs to completion if it is running with a traditional windows service account.

Is this a limitation on GMSA's?

Thanks.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://serverfault.com/q/702651), same error code, _(0xE0434352 is hex for -532462766)_.

Comment: I read that post.  I see no build up of stale processes on the server.  The GMSA has proper access to the remote folder, and since the scheduled task is running as a GMSA, it is not a password issue.

Comment: Your question mentioned that you could not find any information on that error code, I told you the hex equivalent, and there is information available on that. So instead of negative responses only to counter whatever was posted previously, how about you focus on the positive, thank me, and look up information on the hex error code I provided.

Comment: My apologies.  Thank you.